# Pass content of textview to mail message body

Tags: android, email, android-intent, textview

I want to pass the content of textview to be in the message body
 the button works fine for opening and sending mail, 
but how do I add the textview inside the message body?

```
enter code  public class Buy1Activity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageUpload imgUploadObj = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("selected_image_upload");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy1);
    TextView txa = (TextView) findViewById(tx);




    txa.setText( " Name : " +
            imgUploadObj.getName() + "\n" + " Brand : " + imgUploadObj.getBrand() +
            "\n" + " Model : " + imgUploadObj.getModel() + "\n" + " Year : " +
            imgUploadObj.getYear() + "\n" + " price : " + imgUploadObj.getPrice() +
            "\n" + " desc + : " + imgUploadObj.getDesc());


    Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendEmail1);

    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendEmail();
        }
    });

}




protected void sendEmail() {
    Log.i("Send email", "");
    String[] TO = {"201416134@omancollege.edu.om"};
    String[] CC = {""};


    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "whant to buy item");





    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        finish();
        Log.i(" Mail sent...", "");
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(Buy1Activity.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}here

my xml

```
enter code <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tx"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="TextView" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendEmail1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/compose_email"/>
```

here
  this  is my full java and xml codes  without editing any thing maybe i make that cause any error because i'm very beginner

Comment: Do you want to pass the text of this - TextView txa. Into your message body

Comment: yes, the content of this text is already being passed from listview then i want the content of the textview to be in my message body

Comment: mohamed check my below answer,

Comment: and you are taking textview refernce wrongly , use this code from below answer  TextView txa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tx);
in place of your old code  TextView txa = (TextView) findViewById(tx);

Comment: hi Mohanmed , share your error and code pls

Comment: i add my full codes and xml  without editing on them because iam beginner probably i'm add the codes in wrong way

Comment: ok bro let me check them and just do one more thing show me what error you are getting there

Comment: can you paste your error also here

Comment: hello https://stackoverflow.com/users/9010748/mohamed-mo  i have added the required changes in your code , take from the answer and use that code , and test and let me know

Comment: did you try it Mohamed

Comment: it show error here " sendEmail(txa.getText().toString());"  variable txa is accessed from within inner class,need to be declared final

Comment: ok just do one thing replace this line     TextView txa = (TextView) findViewById(tx);
-----------------------with ---------------------------

   final TextView txa = (TextView) findViewById(tx);

Comment: are you able to build it now

Comment: thank you very much , it works perfectly

Comment: your welcome mohamed mo :)

Comment: i don't know how with this answer,but i did it for the other answer with different acount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take the content of your TextView and send as mail body , then you do like this :-

First take content of your textview and store in a String

```
TextView txa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tx);

String textViewContent = txa.getText().toString();
```

and then you can send this as message body :

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,textViewContent);
```

I have edited your code , please take this code and run your app again

```
 public class Buy1Activity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy1);
    TextView txa = (TextView) findViewById(tx);


 ImageUpload imgUploadObj = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("selected_image_upload");


    txa.setText( " Name : " +
            imgUploadObj.getName() + "\n" + " Brand : " + imgUploadObj.getBrand() +
            "\n" + " Model : " + imgUploadObj.getModel() + "\n" + " Year : " +
            imgUploadObj.getYear() + "\n" + " price : " + imgUploadObj.getPrice() +
            "\n" + " desc + : " + imgUploadObj.getDesc());


    Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendEmail1);

    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendEmail(txa.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}




protected void sendEmail(String yourContent) {
    Log.i("Send email", "");
    String[] TO = {"201416134@omancollege.edu.om"};
    String[] CC = {""};


    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "whant to buy item");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,yourContent);





    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        finish();
        Log.i(" Mail sent...", "");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(Buy1Activity.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: sorry , no it's not working , it shows no errors but the app close when i open this activity

Comment: show me your complete code of java and xml too and pls show what is the error you are getting so i can solve your problem here

Answer (score 0):

Try this

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
          "Email Body");